# Why wont my PC Boot from SSD?, old intel motherboard with 4 sata ports

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard, clone

Case is like this :-

1. Clone windows 7 for each PC, other PCs with Asus or Gigabyte motherboards have no problem to boot Windows (so far non intel motherboard 5 PCS done and run well)
2. Same case once fix for PC running intel motherboard (DG31PR / DG35EC) get error :0
   `Reboot and select proper boot device` or `Insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key`
3. It's ok. Pull out everything from SATA ports only slot in SSD into SATA port and BIOS boot to the SSD (KINGSTON).
4. again same error `Reboot and select proper boot device` or `Insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key`.
5. I had no idea why? Inside BIOS I can see the SSD (KINGSTON) plus even using conventional HDD windows mode also can go thru the SSD
6. Ok NVM maybe the SSD gged, take new SSD try on others PC, same case.

Comment: I don't think those older Intel boards support AHCI mode for SATA, if you cloned the drives from a machine that used that it might fail to boot... I remember having a weird issue like this year's ago.

Comment: but the board got 4 sata ports as well.. no make sense right ? so do you means must fresh install ?

Comment: Yes, fresh install... Those boards chipsets are very old, they don't support AHCI.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after think and figure all the possibility, since it's no make sense for me. finally i fix it.

1. enable AHCI in registry. [how to enable](https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/17876-enable-ahci-windows-7-a.html)
2. re run clone again.
3. boot with the ssd ( got error for bootmgr, fix it using windows startup repair )
4. windows loading smooth and fast.